# Find all $n$ for which a partition of weights of equal weights is possible

Tags: number-theory

> There is a set of $ n$ coins with distinct integer weights $ w_1, w_2, \ldots , w_n$. It is known that if any coin with weight $ w_k$, where $ 1 \leq k \leq n$, is removed from the set, the remaining coins can be split into two groups of the same weight. (The number of coins in the two groups can be different.) Find all $ n$ for which such a set of coins exists.

I am trying to prove by induction that this holds for all odd $n$ greater than $5$. Here was the proof provided to me:

Let :
$ f = 1*3*....*(2n - 1)$ ( n is odd number)
where * can take $ + , -$
The case n=7 is obvious by some carculation .
Suppose it true for $ 2n + 1$ we will prove for $ 2n + 3$
Easy to check that when we make a transform : chose two odd consecutive and change them sign then we have $ |f' - f| = 2$
If we move a term from the set ${ \{1,...,2n - 1}$ then use the result $ |f' - f| = 2$ we can chose sign for $ 2n + 1,2n + 3$ for which $ f = 0$ (not contain the object which had been moved ) .
Take all terms which have sign + in a set ,the others in a set . Two sets have equal sum.
If we move $ 2n + 3$ or $ 2n + 1$ ,in two case it is quite easy to find the ways by consider two case $ n\equiv 1 (\mod 4)$ and $ n\equiv 3(\mod 4)$
So all all n odd and $ n > 5$ satisfy condition .

I need help understanding firstly why they defined $f$ like that and how it relates to the weights.

Comment: You should probably first accept one of the answers over at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1611164/find-all-n-for-the-coins if you're satisfied that no solution exists for $n=5$

Comment: The weights are $1,3,\ldots,(2n-1)$.  Getting all but one of them to sum to zero is equivalent to splitting into two equal sums: just move all the negatives to the right hand side.

Comment: @Henry Why are the weights all odd numbers?

Comment: Because it seems to work.  For example you want the sum of $n-1$ weights to be even, which happens if each weight is odd when $n$ is odd.  dREaM's answer to your previous question shows that you need all the weights to be of the same parity, and that if they are all even, then dividing by them all by $2$ is also a solution.

Comment: Oh I see we are just trying to give an example. Got it!

Comment: Keep dividing all the weights by $2$ until at least one is odd.  If any of the others are then even, you will fail; so if there is a solution then there is a solution with them all odd.

Comment: @Henry I suppose we could've also tried this for even weights?

Comment: @Henry This solution is a little hard to understand. What does it mean by "we can chose sign for $2n+1$ and $2n+3$ for which $f = 0$". Why do they want the weight to be $0$?